# Importing a library in a netbeans 7 project

Tags: netbeans-7

I have added the following jar file to my project in netbeans:

*json-lib-2.4-jdk15-sources.jar*

I did this by right clicking 'Libraries', and clicking 'Add JAR/Folder'

The problem I have is when I try to access this library in my code.  I try the following:

`import net.sf.json.JSONObject;`

but I get the message 'package net.sf.json.JSONObject does not exist'.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use

> CTRL + SHIFT + i

netbeans would automatically import the required libraries.

Comment: This does not work.  All I get is a message saying <No Classes Found>

Comment: Please make sure that you are importing the right jar file. If you are importing the right one, check if the jar does contain the api you are trying to use

Comment: Yes.  It is the .jar file I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Why don't you copy the jar file in the 'lib' folder of your application. Then try to import the jar file like you did earlier. Make sure that you use the jar file from the lib folder.

Comment: My application does not have a 'lib' folder.  Should I create one?

Comment: Just to clarify! you're using Netbeans 7. By default when you create an application in netbeans it automatically creates a lib folder. You can check the same in the project view or go to the applications folder and try to find the same.

Comment: In the project window, try to expand the 'Libraries' folder of your application and check if the jar you just added is present or not. Can you see it there?

Comment: Yes I am using netbeans 7.  And yes the jar file is listed under the libraries folder in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured it out!

I was importing the wrong JSON jar file

The file 'json-lib-2.4-jdk15-sources.jar' is wrong.

It's supposed to be 'json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar'